# Form submit button with css sprites?

Tags: css, sprite

I am having a problem creating a form submit button with css sprites. It's just a button with an onrollover state. I have this .css button part

```
.buttonSubmit {
```

background-image: url(../imgs/button_states_submit.png);
 background-repeat:no-repeat;
 margin-top: 10px;
 float:left;
 height: 100px;
 width: 160px;
    }
    a.buttonSubmit:hover {
     background-position:0 -100px;
    }

And i the html i have

```
<input name="" value="" class="buttonSubmit" type="image" />
```

The button submits the form but the onrollover state doesn't work???
When i test with a simple a href the onrollover state works, but i don't know which jQuery selector to use to submit the form

```
<a href="#" id="buttonSubmit" class="buttonSubmit"></a>
```

in combo with jQuery

```
$('#buttonSumbit').click(function(){
```

regards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your CSS:

```
.buttonSubmit {
    background-image: url(../imgs/button_states_submit.png); 
    background-repeat:no-repeat; 
    margin-top: 10px; 
    float:left; 
    height: 100px; 
    width: 160px; 
} 
a.buttonSubmit:hover { background-position:0 -100px; }
```

Note that in the second selector you are using an `<a>` tag which has `.buttonSubmit` class. I guess you want to use an `input` selector:

```
input.buttonSubmit:hover { background-position:0 -100px; }
```

Comment: tx i had to alter the code a bit but your suggestion helped a lot